# Задача на распаковку числа double64 из файла по формату ieee754

Tags: c, python-3.x, числа, double, ieee-754

Мне нужно записать в файл code.bin
число в формате double64,записывается так
1s11e52m,где числа количества бит,
s-знак чила(+ 1,- 0),e-смещенная экспонента,m-мантисса.
Записываю в файл питоном.

```
#genDoub.py
from struct import pack

def write(double_val):
    f=open('code.bin','wb')
    p=pack('<d',double_val)
    f.write(p)
    f.close()
```

Из питон REPL

```
>>>from genDoub import *
>>>write(20.7)
```

Получаю файл code.bin
такой:

```
33333³4@
```

Теперь мне нужно восстановить число из файла на C
таким кодом

```
#include <stdint.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
long double unpack754(uint64_t i, unsigned bits, unsigned expbits) {
    long double result;
    long long shift;
    unsigned bias;
    unsigned significandbits = bits - expbits - 1; // -1 для бита знака
    // вычисляем биты от мантиссы,значимые биты,для 32val M_biti=23,для
    //64val это M_biti=52

    if (i == 0) return 0.0;

    // устанавливаем значимость
    result = (i & ((1LL << significandbits) - 1)); // маска

    result /= (1LL << significandbits); // Конвертируем обратно во float
    result += 1.0f; // прибавляем обратно
    // разбираемся с экспонентой
    bias = (1 << (expbits - 1)) - 1;
    shift = ((i >> significandbits)&((1LL << expbits) - 1)) - bias;
    while (shift > 0) {
        result *= 2.0;
        shift--;
    }
    while (shift < 0) {
        result /= 2.0;
        shift++;
    }
    // получаем результат
    result *= (i >> (bits - 1))&1 ? -1.0 : 1.0;

    return result;


}

unsigned char* readF(const char* filename) {
    unsigned char *cc;
    FILE *fp;
    // чтение из файла
    if ((fp = fopen(filename, "rb")) == NULL) {
        perror("Error occured while opening file");
        exit(2);
    }
    // пока не дойдем до конца, считываем по 256 байт
    while (fread(cc, 1, 256, fp) != NULL) {

    }

    fclose(fp);
    return cc;
}
int main(int argc, char** argv) {
  unsigned char* bytes=readF("code.bin");
  printf("%s\n",bytes);
  uint64_t v=(bytes[3]+bytes[2]+bytes[1]+bytes[0]);
  printf("%d\n",v);
  long double ld=unpack754(v,64,11);
  printf("%d\n",ld);

    return 0;
}
```

Получаю

```
33333▒4@
204
417792
```

Я должен получить 20.7,получаю 417792.Это неправильно. Т.е. я неправильно видимо число v передаю,я его собрал как 204.

Что я в unpack754 должен передавать?
Доработал как советовали,такой код лучше работает,но полностью число не восстановил:

```
#include <stdint.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
double d;

long double unpack754(uint64_t i, unsigned bits, unsigned expbits) {
    long double result;
    long long shift;
    unsigned bias;
    unsigned significandbits = bits - expbits - 1; // -1 для бита знака
    // вычисляем биты от мантиссы,значимые биты,для 32val M_biti=23,для
    //64val это M_biti=52

    if (i == 0) return 0.0;

    // pull the significand
    result = (i & ((1LL << significandbits) - 1)); // маска

    result /= (1LL << significandbits); // Конвертируем обратно во float
    result += 1.0f; // прибавляем обратно
    // разбираемся с экспонентой
    bias = (1 << (expbits - 1)) - 1;
    shift = ((i >> significandbits)&((1LL << expbits) - 1)) - bias;
    while (shift > 0) {
        result *= 2.0;
        shift--;
    }
    while (shift < 0) {
        result /= 2.0;
        shift++;
    }
    // получаем результат
    result *= (i >> (bits - 1))&1 ? -1.0 : 1.0;

    return result;


}

unsigned char* readF(const char* filename) {
    unsigned char *cc;
    FILE *fp;

    // чтение из файла
    if ((fp = fopen(filename, "rb")) == NULL) {
        perror("Error occured while opening file");
        exit(2);
    }
    //    // пока не дойдем до конца, считываем по 256 байт
    //    while (fread(cc, 1, 256, fp) != NULL) {
    //
    //    }
    fread(&d, sizeof (d), 1, fp);
    printf("%d\n", d);


    fclose(fp);
    return cc;
}

int main(int argc, char** argv) {

    readF("code.bin");

    double ld = unpack754(d, 64, 11);
    printf("%d\n", ld);

    return 0;
}
```

Выдает последний print как

```
10
```

Comment: код у вас пишет в little-endian binary64 формате. Вы именно это под "double64" подразумевали? Почему бы просто `fread(&d, sizeof(d), 1, file)` не вызвать? (если машина с little-endian `double d`, которая тоже binary64 использует) Если есть желание ручками туда/сюда биты попреобразовывать, то вот [пример на Питоне для binary16](https://gist.github.com/zed/59a413ae2ed4141d2037)

Comment: Так а что это за чтение в неинициализированный указатель `cc`? Или это лишь частичный код?

Comment: Да под double64 имел binary64.C указателем что то не так)

Comment: @jfs там по идее struct.pack должен работать и сделал я по вашему совету,уже лучше)

Comment: если бы вы последовали моему совету, то в вашей программе не было бы вызова `unpack754()` вообще. Результат в `d` переменной уже (глобальной не нужно переменной, локально объявление добавьте, включите все warnings в компиляторе). Ничего дальше не нужно делать.

Comment: Вообще то я имел ввиду что частично по совету,unpack обязательно нужен,сейчас все внимательнее сделал и все вроде работает,но я хочу сделть вирт. машину и мне нужно взять 8 байт как параметр и как то складывать или что то еще делать с ними(именно как параметр опкода)